# Rails Internal Messaging System for mongo db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for a gem that implements an internal messaging system like [mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer)

This gem does not support mongomapper and I'm looking for something that fully support mongodb.

Is there any clever way to implement this or do I have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: Is this for messaging or notifications?